# Possible to end one particular session in IIS (without recycling the whole site)?

Tags: session, iis-7.5

This question has been asked many times over the years, so apologies for trying again ... but maybe progress has occurred since the last time it was considered insoluble.

I have a web application on IIS 7.5 where users may interact for long periods of time.  Occasionally, I need to do heavy maintenance lasting around ten minutes, and certain user requests during the maintenance would cause problems.  I could, of course, pause the app using its admin features, and restart the website in IIS, killing all user sessions.  Everyone would be forced to log in again, and those affected by the maintenance could be forced to wait until the maintenance was finished before they were allowed to log in again.  But sometimes this would cause inconvenience to lots of users not affected by the maintenance.  It would be great to be able to end just selective user sessions, only the ones affected.  Is that possible with IIS?  IIS is obviously capable of ending individual sessions when they time out, after N minutes of inactivity, and it would be great to have the ability to trigger that time-out selectively ahead of schedule when needed.

I can't even find a way to get a list of live sessions, much less selectively end them.

Comment: Sessions are something above HTTP, and IIS has no idea of their existence, while your applications (and the frameworks, like PHP, ASP.NET) fully control that. Even the time out is not controlled by IIS at all. No matter how many times it has been asked, such a question won't have its answer.

Comment: My application is ASP classic.  The existence of the session, and the timeout length, and lots of other properties of the application are administered through IIS manager, so it's fair to say that IIS exposes a lot of those application details for administration.   So maybe the question should be restated as:  does IIS expose any feature in ASP classic or related frameworks that would kill individual sessions (even if the trigger is not ultimately pulled by IIS itself)?

Comment: asp.dll itself is a smallish file whose only role, as I understood, was to interpret scripts.  I assumed the session was managed by IIS, but perhaps it's really managed by the dot.net framework or some other component.  So maybe the question could also be expressed as:  is there a separate management utility, other than IIS manager, for whatever it is that manages sessions for asp classic applications?  And could that other utility possibly provide the feature of ending individual sessions?

Comment: Classic ASP is dead for 15 years and more. Its built in session mode is in process and is controlled by a few settings of ˋasp.dll` so what you get today is what was designed decades ago, and you don’t really have a true solution but switching to a modern web framework.

Comment: OK, never mind.  ASP classic is a brilliant little thing, much under-rated.  It's too bad Microsoft didn't hand it over to the open source community to keep alive.